# trying to understand access tomembers within a package

Tags: java

Good morning

I am learning Java and trying to understand the access to class members inside a package.
I have to files in MemberAccess directory and called the package unitOne.MemberAccess(is that right?)

Here is the simple example.

```
package unitOne.MemberAccess;

public class Parent 
{
    private String secret = "This is my secret"; 
    protected String inherit = "All my money";

    int age = 100; 

    public void singInShower()
    {
        System.out.println("la-di-da");
    }
}
```

new I created a seperate file in the same package called OtherPerson.

```
package unitOne.MemberAccess;

class OtherPerson
{


    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        OtherPerson op = new OtherPerson();
        System.out.println(op.inherit);
        System.out.println(op.age);
    }   

}
```

The problem is that I get a compile time error explaining to me that the symbol cannot be found.
But in my understanding protected and default members in the same package as another class can be viewed by that class.

Regards
Arian

Comment: It is common convention to make package names all lowercase. Your use of capital letters in the package name is not wrong, but it is rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A member of one class (whether private, public, protected or default) is `Never` visible to other Class. NEVER....That would be a night mare. Accessing other members and visibility of other members come into play when one class Inherits other class. So either you need to extend class, implement parent child relationship. Then what you are saying would be true

and yes, where I live, its `Good Evening` here at this point of time :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 OtherPerson op = new OtherPerson();
```

`op` is an instance of type **OtherPerson**. The **OtherPerson** and **Parent** classes has no relation and thus `op` cannot be used to access **Parent** class members.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create object of Parent class in Otherperson class.

So, you need to write `Parent op = new Parent()` instead of   `OtherPerson op = new OtherPerson();`

Answer (score 1):

Your `OtherPerson` doesn't inherit your `Parent`.

Try replacing the second line of your OtherPerson.java with `class OtherPerson extends Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

`op` is an `OtherPerson` object and has no `age` property. The class `Parent` has an age property, though. Replacing `OtherPerson op = new OtherPerson();` with `Parent op = new Parent();` should work.